# How to clear fields after callback from axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have modal component with form. I want to inform fields of this form that form data was successfully sent to database and clear its fields.

Component code:

```
//ItemModal.js

addItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const item = {
      id: this.props.itemsStore.length + 1,
      image: this.fileInput.files[0] || 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
      tags: this.tagInput.value,
      place: this.placeInput.value,
      details: this.detailsInput.value
    }
    console.log('addded', item);
    this.props.onAddItem(item);
    this.fileInput.value = '';
    this.tagInput.value = '';
    this.placeInput.value = '';
    this.detailsInput.value = '';
    this.setState({
      filled: { 
        ...this.state.filled, 
        place: false, 
        tags: false 
      },
      loadingText: 'Loading...'
    });
  }
```

...

```
render() {
    return (
            <div className="text-center" > 
            <div className={"text-center form-notification " + ((this.state.loadingText) ? 'form-notification__active' : '' )}>
              {(this.state.loadingText) ? ((this.props.loadingState === true) ? 'Item added' : this.state.loadingText) : '' }
            </div>
    )
}
```

action.js

```
export function onAddItem(item) {
          axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/items/', item )
            .then(res => {
              dispatch({type:"ADD_ITEM", item});
              dispatch({type:"ITEM_LOADED", status: true});
            })
}
```

helper.js

```
else if (action.type === 'ITEM_LOADED') {
    const status = action.status;
    return {
      ...state,
      isItemLoaded: status
    }
  }
```

Currently I have few issues with my code:
1. field are clearing right after click, but they should clear after changing state of `loadingState`. I tried to check it in separate function on in componentWillReceiveProps whether state is changed and it worked, but I faces another problem, that after closing this modal there were errors, that such fields doesn't exist.
2. `loadingText` should become `''` (empty) after few seconds. Tried same approach with separate function and componentWillReceiveProps as at first issue.

Comment: return promise form `onAddItem` function and after that empty your fields.

Comment: @Justcode how to it?

Answer (score 0):

In constructor keep a copy of your initial state in a const as follows:

```
const stateCopy = Object.create(this.state);
```

When your ajax request completes, in the sucess callback you can reset the state with this copy as follows:

```
this.setStae({
...stateCopy
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the few ways to achieve this is to use async await which will resolve the promises and then return the value after that you can clear the values

1st approach using the async await

---

Here is the [example](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/#using-async-and-await)

```
handleSubmit = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Promise is resolved and value is inside of the response const.
  const response = await API.delete(`users/${this.state.id}`);
  //dispatch your reducers
};
```

Now in your react component call it

```
PostData() {
        const res = await handleSubmit();
        //empty your model and values
    }
```

Second approach is to use the timer to check the value is changed or not

---

for this we need one variable add this to the service

```
let timerFinished=false;
```

one function to check it is changed or not

```
CheckTimers = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (timerFinished) {
            //empty your modal and clear the values
        } else {
            this.CheckTimers();
        }
    }, 200);
}
```

on your add item change this variable value

```
export function onAddItem(item) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/items/', item)
        .then(res => {
            timerFinished = true;
            dispatch({
                type: "ADD_ITEM",
                item
            });
            dispatch({
                type: "ITEM_LOADED",
                status: true
            });
        })
}
```

and here is how we need to call it.

```
PostData = (items) => {
    timerFinished = false;
    onAddItem(items);
    this.CheckTimers();    
}
```

If you check this what we done is continuously checking the variable change and emptied only once its done.

One thing you need to handle is to when axios failed to post the data you need to change the variable value to something and handle it, you can do it using the different values `'error','failed','success'` to the `timerFinished` variable.